# wordpress: submitted data from a form working only depending on the redirect url

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, redirect

I read a lot of posts talking about issues concerning redirection after form submit but I didn't find any that seems to solve my problem.

I create a quiz website with wordpress.
Each single.php template contains a question.
I use a form to post the data (in the database) which are chosen by the user.
I use the action attribute of the form to redirect to the next post (next question). So far everything works properly, data are stored in the database and users are redirected to the next post. 
But when I reach the last post I've set a condition to redirect to a specific page. The redirection works nicely but the data of this last question are not submitted in my database...

Here is my code :

```
<?php $redirect_url = 0;
    if ($currentID !== $nextID):
        // NEXT POST
        $redirect_url = get_permalink($nextID);
    else:
        // SPECIFIC PAGE (END QUIZ)
        $redirect_url = get_permalink(24);
    endif; 
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $redirect_url; ?>" id="stat_form" class="hidden">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="c1" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="c2" value="2">
    <input type="number" name="replay" id="replay" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST['replay']); ?>">
    <input type="number" name="question_id" id="question_id" value="<?php echo $currentID; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php 
// SAVE INFO IN DATABASE
// ---------------------
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) ) {
    $table = $wpdb->prefix."stats_questions";
    $question_ID = strip_tags($_POST['question_id']);
    $choice = strip_tags($_POST['choice']);
    $replay = strip_tags($_POST['replay']);
    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table, array( 
            'question_ID' => (int) $question_ID,
            'choice' => (int) $choice,
            'replay' => (int) $replay,
        )
    );
}
// ---------------------
?>
```

Comment: add your saving code in redirected page

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't seem to work... It seemed like a good solution though

Comment: Ohhhh my bad, I put the code in the wrong place. 
Your solution works great !! Thanks a lot

Comment: I thought datas was sent just before redirecting !
So just to be sure to understand, datas are sent to the database only when the indicated redirect page is loaded ?

Comment: did you check by print_r($_POST) in your redirectd page is any data is sent or not

Comment: I just checked. And even without the saving code on the end game page my datas were submitted. But to have them saved in the database I needed the saving code on this last page.